# SQL join concept and constraints of keys

Tags: sql

I have question about conceptual difference between JOIN and constraints. We are using primary key and foreign key relationship in building models.

But if we can use JOINs to build any kind of left/full/inner relationships, why do we need constraints? Adding reference for further reading will be appreciated.

Comment: Joins don't have to be on equalities `ON a.id = 2 * b.id` might be logical jibberish, but it's perfectly valid syntax.  A constraint is just a mechanism to ensure data written to a table confirms to specific rules, such as a `team_id` may have a foreign key constraint, so that it can only accept values which actually exist in a `team` table. You COULD set everything up without the constraint, but then you'd be allowed to insert invalid data and can't tell if your data is internally consistent without running a query. (Referential integrity, ACID's 'consistency'.)

Comment: @devlincarnate : No, constraints are used to limit the data that is allowed to BE in your tables when a DML happens (INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE). The WHERE clause limits the data returned by your query; a JOIN can also do that, or a HAVING clause, or probably other instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOINs lets you construct queries for *retrieving* data from related tables. For example, if you have a Teachers table and a Classes table like this

```
CREATE Teachers (TeacherId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, TeacherName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
CREATE Classes (ClassID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, TeacherId INT NOT NULL,
 ClassName VARCHAR(100));
```

a query that JOINs them

```
SELECT T.TeacherId, T.TeacherName, C.ClassId, C.ClassName 
FROM Teachers T
INNER JOIN Classes C on T.TeacherId=C.TeacherId
```

will let you find the Classes that each Teacher is teaching.

JOINs can be used to join any two tables, even if there is no meaningful relationship between them:

```
SELECT T.* FROM Teachers 
INNER JOIN Reptiles R
  On R.ReptileId = T.TeacherId
```

Foreign Key CONSTRAINTs let you prevent insertion of data that violates the constraint. Or prevent deletion of data that would result in violation of a constraint.  For example, a foreign key constraint between the Teachers and Classes tables

```
ALTER TABLE Classes
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Teacher_Class FOREIGN KEY (TeacherId)
      REFERENCES Teachers (TeacherId)
```

would prevent you from deleting a Teacher if they still are registered as teaching at least one Class; it would also prevent you from Inserting a class that had no Teacher, or modifying a Class to have a TeacherId with no matching Teacher row.

Also, there are other kinds of constraints, for example CHECK constraints control what values a particular column is allowed to have.

In modern DBMSes, the existence of constraints can be used to optimize a SQL query so it is far more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

I think that constraints are used to not allow the deletion of a data in an array knowing that it is related to another.
Basically, it's data protection.